# laptop battery maintenance

Tags: laptop

I have about 2 spare batteries and I would like to know how many weeks / days I can leave a battery uncharged without damaging it.I would be away for about a week or 2, so I 
I hope to get some response. Thanks in advance

Comment: Read this article http://www.howtogeek.com/169669/debunking-battery-life-myths-for-mobile-phones-tablets-and-laptops/

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of thumb for [Li-Ion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery) or [LiPo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) batteries is that you want to store them at somewhere between 30% to 50% of full charge if they are not going to be used for long periods of time (weeks or months).

You should *never* allow a Li-Ion or LiPo battery to remain at less than 10% of charge for any significant amount of time.  If you run your battery pack flat, you should charge it to at least 30% charge as soon as you possibly can.

If you are simply concerned about how long you can leave a Li-Ion or LiPo battery alone without it being damaged: don't worry about it so long as the battery has at least 30% charge in it.